# JHAT cannot analyze a memory dump

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory, jhat

I have a Memory Dump file and JHAT gives the following message and I cannot analyze anything (as no data is displayed.

```
 Resolving 0 objects...

WARNING:  hprof file does not include java.lang.Class!

WARNING:  hprof file does not include java.lang.String!

WARNING:  hprof file does not include java.lang.ClassLoader!
```

Does this mean the hprof file is incomplete or corrupt?

I am using
`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"`
option in my tomcat.

Comment: Have you tried opening this dump with another profiler (e.g. YourKit?)

Comment: yourkit is not free, cannot afford to buy it.

Comment: YourKit has a trial version that you can use for 30 days (or so).  Try that first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just came across this same issue with my own heap dump.

- jhat shows the warnings you describe, and there's no useful data displayed
- Eclipse MAT complains about a `NullPointerException`
- VisualVM can't open the heap dump file at all

It looks like this happens when there is not enough disk space at the time that the heap is dumped, so the file is indeed incomplete/corrupt.

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1175621&tstart=135

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today.  To clarify, I am using the option `heap=sites` which is different than a memory dump.  I also get the same messages from `jhat` and `jvisualvm`.  It is possible that `jhat` does not support reading `HPROF` files created by `heap=sites` mode.